# iOS 8 Custom Keyboard for native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard

Can I develop keyboard extension for my app (only). Keyboard extension must work only in app not in all system.

I know about apple guide:

> BEFORE YOU BEGIN
>
> Make sure a custom, systemwide keyboard is indeed what you want to
>   develop. To provide a fully custom keyboard for just your app or to
>   supplement the system keyboard with custom keys in just your app, the
>   iOS SDK provides other, better options. Read about custom input views
>   and input accessory views in Custom Views for Data Input in Text
>   Programming Guide for iOS.

This methods offer only supplement the standard keyboards. I want fully customization keyboard in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to create a keyboard extension, since it will be replace your keyboard in every application.

`UITextView` and `UITextField` have both `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView` properties.

`inputAccessoryView` is a view that appears on top of the keyboard, while `inputView` replaces the keyboard with the view you provide for the current editing field.

You can create your keyboard in a xib and instantiate it in the inputView property of your textField.

More details on [Text Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html)

---

Why your question is `iOS 8 Custom Keyboard for native app`? you ask a different thing in your post…

Comment: ok, but user can't select other keyboard languages or emoji keyboard, in this case I must release other keyboards too?

Comment: @dev.nikolaz what I do in one of my apps is create an inputAccesoryView which has a button to show or hide my custom keyboard which is used as an inputView. This way the use can use both your custom keyboard and the default keyboards.